# Batch File: Copying Files and Redirecting Output

Tags: batch-file, redirect, copy

I work in the IT department at a company with a few hundred computers. We are switching to a new piece of software that is essential to everyone's job. I have 2 batch files. The first one just copies a program shortcut to the desktop. The second one is the one I need advice on. I need it to copy the first batch file to the startup folder on each computer, so at startup the first batch file will check for the desktop icon and copy it to the desktop if it isn't already there. I also need the output of the second batch file to be redirected so I can peruse it later to find out which machines the operation failed on. It points to an Excel file that has the PC names that it needs to reach out to and copy files to.

Here's what I have:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (c:\temp\machinenames.csv) (
    if not exist "\\%%A\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\CopyBlueZoneshortcut.bat" do (
        copy "\\msfs0965\data1\share\everyone\BlueZone\CopyBlueZoneshortcut.bat" "\\%%A\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
    )
)
```

I tried adding ">> results.txt 2>&1" at the end to redirect output, but it doesn't write to file.

Thank you everyone for looking over my post and lending me a hand. I appreciate you all. Thank you for your patience with me as well. I've written a couple of bat and vbs files before, but I'm still fairly novice at this.

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window and enter `if /?`, to read its usage information. Then tell us where you see a `do` statement. Then repeat the process with `for /?` and tell us whether you see a `do` statement. Then please reconsider your strategy, the 'StartUp' directory is for shortcuts to exectuable files, not for those executables. Please only place shortcuts, `.lnk` or possibly `.url` files within that location.

Comment: If you would do basic troubleshooting you would have at least seen that your batch file is immediately failing because of incorrect syntax. In the future, execute your batch files from the command prompt and make sure you do not have `ECHO OFF` in your code.

Comment: I'll run if /? in cmd tomorrow at work and see how it goes.

I don't have echo off in the code. What you see is what I have in the batch file.

My manager started this script on his own and passed it onto me yesterday when he got a little busy. I think his idea is that people delete icons all the time and he wants this icon on the desktop on every machine, and what's one more batch file running at the time users log in. With that said, if there is a better option for making sure this icon is on the desktop when a user logs in, I'm happy to listen to other options.

Thank you for the help